# Css Media with initial scale=1 and positioning div on screen

Tags: html, css

I'm using a media query to set my style content on Iphone.
This all looks great except I want to add padding around the wrapper. When I add 20px to the left and right it adds it but it's pushing it to the right off the screen. I thought by adding it to the right would push it back in 20px from the left of the browser screen so I would get some nice margins on each side of the wrapper. 
How would I correct this so there is 20px of white space on both sides of the wrapper.

```
<head>
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1' />
</head>

    <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <p id="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud.</p>
        <p id="copy">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
    </div>
    </body>

        @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
            #wrapper {
                width: 100%;
                background-color: red;
                margin-left: 20px;
                margin-right: 20px;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set `width:100%` and margin or border or padding beacuse it increases all the total width = Over the 100% of the browsers size.

What you can do is use this CSS3 property

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

That makes all your new values of `padding` or `border` to be inside the width. It doesn't count the margin so what you can do is set your body with padding and this property:

```
body {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding:20px;
}
```

View the Demo File **http://jsfiddle.net/tjQLG/**

See more about here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp.

Comment: box-sizing:border-box; was exactly what I needed thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
            body{
                margin-left: 20px;
                margin-right: 20px;
            }
        }
```

Hope this helps.